# How do I run jsx files in the context of a node package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have installed all my dependencies via `npm install` and laid down the basic plumbing for a React/Redux app:

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

let initialState = {};
let rootReducer = function() {};

let store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

let app = React.createClass({});

ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <app/>
        </Provider>,
        document.body
);
```

I know I can type `jsx main.jsx` to compile this file, but doing so will not do it in the context of the node package it is in and my imports will not work. How do I compile this file in the context of my node package?

Comment: Transpile your code to be published via babel.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way to render your `.jsx` code to a html view. 
First way to is to compile `.jsx` file to `.js` file in order the make app logic work,

for example use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jsx.

Another way is add a view engine that support jsx eg. https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views.
It is depends on your application design to determine which approach is best solution .

Answer (score 0):

I use babel to transpile all my code to ES5 javascript. It will handle JSX if you use the [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/).

Assuming your code is in `./src` and you are going to compile it to `./lib`.

**Install these packages:**

`npm i --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`

**add a .babelrc file to the root of your app (next to package.json) with the following**

```
{
 "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

**then add the following script to package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files"
}
```

Now you can just run `npm run build` to compile your files, and then you can run from `./lib`. Probably also a good idea to set your app entry point to something like `lib/index.js` so you can still run the app with `node .`. In addition, you will be able to use things like `import` and other ES6 features. If you don't care about that bit, you can drop the 
es2015 preset.